# How to use begin with selector in Less

Tags: css-selectors, less

I'm going to create a less code that will give different `background-color` to element depending on it's class. This will be for list of attachments, so class name is based on attachment extension.

I do support some typical extensions:

```
.label{
    &.label-pdf{
        background-color: #c70000;
    }

    &.label-doc, &.label-docx, &.label-odt{
        background-color: #157efb;
    }

    &.label-xls, &.label-xlsx, &.label-calc{
        background-color: #069e00;
    }

    &.label-ppt, &.label-pptx, &.label-odp{
        background-color: #9e3c15;
    }

    &.label-jpg, &.label-png, &.label-gif, &.label-png, &.label-ttf{
        background-color: #95009e;
    }
}
```

but the problem is with some unusual extensions, or even files like: `jpg`, `jpeg`, `doc`, `docx`, this is why I would like to use expression from CSS. In pure CSS I could use:

```
    .label.[class^="label-"]{
        background-color: rgba(0,37,100,0.4);
    }
```

And put this code at the beginning so other classes could override this one.
But unfortunately this sign `^` (I suppose) is breaking my Less compilation. I have been trying to do something like this:

```
~".label.[class^='label-']{
    background-color: rgba(0,37,100,0.4);
}"
```

AND

```
.label{
    &.~"[class^='label-']"{
        background-color: rgba(0,37,100,0.4);
    }
}
```

But still not working. So is it possible to use this selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not working because your syntax seems to be wrong and not because of any issues with Less.

The below code is invalid because of the `.` present between the `label` and the `class^="label-"]`. Attribute selectors do not require a `.` before them. It is necessary only for class selectors.

```
.label.[class^="label-"]{
    background-color: rgba(0,37,100,0.4);
}
```

The correct version would be the following:

```
.label[class^="label-"]{
    background-color: rgba(0,37,100,0.4);
}
```

and so in Less terms, if you want nesting, it would be as follows:

```
.label{ 
    &[class^='label-']{
        background-color: rgba(0,37,100,0.4);
    }
}
```

```css
.label.[class^="label-"] {  /* this won't work */
  background-color: rgba(0, 37, 100, 0.4);
}

.label[class^="label-"] {  /* this will */
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<label class='label-a label'>Label A</label>
<label class='label-b label'>Label B</label>
```

---

Another thing to note is that the `^=` is a starts with selector and so when your element has more than one class, the class that resembles `label-` should be the first class in the list and not the `label`. If we make the `label` as the first class then (like seen in below snippet) it won't work because then the class ***doesn't start with*** `label-`.

If the first class in the list is indeed `label` then you should consider using the `*=` (contains) selector. But be careful when using the contains selector because it will sometimes select unintended elements like those with class `label-not`, `not-label` etc.

```css
.label.[class^="label-"] {  /* this won't work */
  background-color: rgba(0, 37, 100, 0.4);
}

.label[class^="label-"] {  /* this won't too */
  color: green;
}

.label[class*="label-"] {  /* this will */
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<label class='label label-a'>Label A</label>
<label class='label label-b'>Label B</label>
```

Comment: I have made an error, there should be `.label` cause it is for CSS class. And after I did remove `.` from `.label.[class^="label-"]` and now LESS is compiling with no error, but still don't work as suppose. Now my selector is: `.label [class^="label-"]`. PS I have update my code and add needed `.` in label

Comment: @bumerang: If you are nesting the attribute selector then you should write it as `&[class^='label-']` (note that there is no space between the & and the [). If there is a space introduced then it means that the attribute selector (that is, the `[class=...]` part) corresponds to a child element and not another class on the same element.

Comment: Yes You are right, I was going to give pure CSS (not LESS) selector, and give an space in my comment.

Comment: To make it work, I was forced to change the order of classes in element: `<span class="label-extension label">extension</span>`

Comment: Yeah, I thought you might have that problem and was actually editing that into the answer :)

Comment: I was going to ask You for that. Now Your answer is fully complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I use this in less file.

```
[class^="customForm-"] { ... }
```

But for my HTML it does not works.

```
<div class="form form-01 customForm-radioList">...</div>
```

The problem is in tha fact that string "form form-01 customForm-radioList" does not starts with "customForm-" it starts with "form".

**Solution**

Use *contains* selector [W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

```
[class*="customForm-"] { ... }
```